# Problema para crear Claves Foraneas MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para mi tecnicatura, estoy creando una base de datos de un hotel.
mi problema esta en las claves foraneas.
Esta es mi tabla huesped: (pasaporte seria mi PK)
[image]

Esta es mi tabla Reserva: (pasaporte_huesped seria mi FK)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando quiero hacer la FK desde reserva me sale este error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `bd_hoteleria`.`reserva` 
ADD INDEX `fk_huesped_pasaporte_idx` (`pasaporte_huesped` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `bd_hoteleria`.`reserva` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_huesped_pasaporte`
  FOREIGN KEY (`pasaporte_huesped`)
  REFERENCES `bd_hoteleria`.`huesped` (`pasaporte`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `bd_hoteleria`.`reserva` 
ADD INDEX `fk_huesped_pasaporte_idx` (`pasaporte_huesped` ASC) VISIBLE
```

Comment: Buenas! Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y leas [ask] y agregues un [example]. Por favor añade el error como texto y no como una imágen. Puedes hacer click en [editar].

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de MySQL usas? Intenta sin la opción `VISIBLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu error es porque estas intentando hacer que tu clave foránea sea la primaria en la tabla reserva. Necesitas un número o código de reserva para llevar la continuidad de tus registros y usar esto como clave primaria. Genere el SQL de tus tablas pero considero que deberías hacer ciertos ajustes como los tipos de dato en los campos teléfono, pasaporte y número de habitación ya que en ocasiones estos valores pueden poseer caracteres alfanuméricos y no solo enteros.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bd_hoteleria`.`huesped` (
  `pasaporte` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `pais` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pasaporte`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bd_hoteleria`.`reserva` (
  `num_reserva` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `huesped_pasaporte` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `num_habitacion` INT(11) NULL,
  `checkin` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkout` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`num_reserva`),
  INDEX `fk_reserva_huesped_idx` (`huesped_pasaporte` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reserva_huesped`
    FOREIGN KEY (`huesped_pasaporte`)
    REFERENCES `bd_hoteleria`.`huesped` (`pasaporte`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```